# Laptop behaving like desktop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, desktop

The windows 10 installed in my laptop behaves like in desktop after an update. The brightness and battery details are missing from the toolbar and elsewhere. Also the laptop keypad & touchpad is not working. Only external usb keyboard, mouse is working. Kindly help.

[image: Screegrab]

Comment: Update the BIOS and then the Power Drivers. Best to update all drivers.

Comment: Have you reinstalled Windows?

Comment: The only thing that would result in a laptop's keypad and touchpad not being recognized in the OS would be a hardware issue, either hardware failure, loose ribbon cable connection on the component and/or motherboard, or a motherboard failure, as these are always recognized via the BIOS/UEFI drivers and/or the generic drivers all mainstream OSes contain - run BIOS/UEFI hardware diagnostics. Taken in aggregate, with the battery and screen brightness controls missing, it's indicative of missing OEM drivers _(e.g. chipset, IMEI, other applicable drivers, etc.)_ or motherboard hardware failure.

Comment: @JW0914 it seems some OEM drivers are missing. Kindly guide how to get them and solve the issue. It's ASUS  Eeebook x205ta.  Thanks :)

Comment: @BodhisattwaBasu You'll find them on your OEM's support site, however it would be more beneficial to run BIOS/UEFI hardware diagnostics before further troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks @JW0914 and all. First I re-installed the chipset driver and the issue resolved. Again updated windows 10 to the latest version, and the problem re-appeared. Then again re-installed chipset driver and laptop is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried rolling back the update

I found ur notebook's driver page: https://www.asus.com/us/supportonly/X205TA/HelpDesk_Download/

the pointing device should be the one for ur touchpad

you might wanna go to device manager and check if ur laptop recognizes the devices first

you might also wanna check 'myasus' from the Microsoft store, they have more features and probably better customer support since it's specifically for Asus devices

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned in my comment on 25 July,21, attached to the question above,  I re-installed the chipset driver and the issue resolved. Again updated windows 10 to the latest version, and the problem re-appeared, again re-installed chipset driver and laptop is working fine.